# Show image depending on select option with custom value attribute

Tags: javascript, html, image, drop-down-menu

What I want to reach:

Show an image depending on select box selection. But I don't want to take attribute `value=""`, I want to take a custom attribute `data-img=""` instead.

This is the code I actually have, but it's not working:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script>
function showFormatImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById("itemImage");
    image.src = $('select[name=itemImage] option:selected').data('img');
    return false;
}
document.getElementById("itemImage").onchange = showFormatImage;
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="itemImage" name="itemImage">
    <option data-img="first.png">First</option>
    <option data-img="second.png">Second</option>
    <option data-img="third.png">Third</option>
</select><br>

<img id="itemImage" src="">

</body>
</html>
```

No image is shown. Does anybody know what's wrong?

*P.S.: If there's a non-Javascript solution, that would be even better but I don't think there is.*

Comment: But you have integrated jquery? Your code (although it is not very clean) works: https://jsfiddle.net/7w1p95yw/

Comment: Oh, you're right. I forgot to integrate jQuery. But, it's still not working.

Comment: Now with jquery check the other answer...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Check the answer of Jameson... But your code in jsfiddle works...

Comment: you've added `id` to the image - but now you have duplicate `id`'s (both are `itemImage`), also there is a simple jquery option in my answer

Comment: @Baro I don't know why, but it doesn't work for me. Does it work for you in Coda or something like this?

Comment: Try with external images and exclude that the problem is related to the images path. And check out this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7w1p95yw/6/

Comment: Still not working. I don't understand it. This is the code I'm trying: https://codeshare.io/25xLI

Comment: @David - it's all about the execution time, you're writing calls the addEventListener before `itemImage` exists and so fails, jsfiddle takes care of that - and that's why it works there

Comment: Yes, that is it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var image = document.getElementById("itemImage");
```

`var image` is the select - not the `img`, also - `itemImage` does not exist at time of execution so the event handler isn't placed.

you should change your code to:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <script>
          window.onload = function() {
              document.getElementById("itemImage").onchange = showFormatImage;
           };
          function showFormatImage() {
             var image = document.getElementById("changeImage");
             image.src = $('select[name=itemImage] option:selected').attr('data-img');
             return false;
          }

         </script>
     </head>
     <body>

       <select id="itemImage" name="itemImage">
             <option data-img="first.png">First</option>
             <option data-img="second.png">Second</option>
             <option data-img="third.png">Third</option>
       </select><br>

         <img src="" id='changeImage'/>
    </body>
</html>
```

jquery solution:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#itemImage').change(function(){
         var src = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-img');
         $('img#changeImage').attr('src',src);
     });
});
```

Comment: None of both works. Does the first code block works for you?

Comment: you know what could be the problem - the timing -you're script is before the HTML and so `itemImage` select does not exist (debug via the console man..) I'm updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

Should replace .data function with .attr(data-img)